# Mule 3.7.0: Multipart file upload with new http connector and jersey

Tags: file, http, upload, jersey, mule

I'm upgrading an app that uses http and jersey to upload a file to Mule 3.7.0 and migrating to the new HTTP implementation. Before updating I was able to upload a file using the following configuration

```
<http:connector name="HttpConnector" >
    <service-overrides messageFactory="org.mule.transport.http.HttpMuleMessageFactory"
        sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler" />
</http:connector>

<flow name="UploadFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://0.0.0.0:8095/sds" connector-ref="HttpConnector"/>
    <jersey:resources>
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="FileUploadResource" />
        </component>
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

where FileUploadResource is

```
@POST
@Path("module/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response uploadModule(@FormDataParam("file") final InputStream is,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails) throws IOException {

    String filename = fileDetails.getFileName();
    .....
}
```

The updated configuration is as follows

```
<http:listener-config name="HttpListenerConfig" host="0.0.0.0" basePath="/sds" port="8095"/>

<flow name="UploadFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HttpListenerConfig" path="/*"/>
    <jersey:resources>
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="FileUploadResource" />
        </component>
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

and FileUploadResource is unchanged. When attempting to upload a file, I receive an HTTP 400 Bad Request error. What is the correct way to migrate this functionality to the new implementation? Thanks in advance.

The upload request is as follows:

```
Host: 192.168.29.129:8095
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://192.168.29.129:8090/mule/
Content-Length: 56068
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------   12776546320886
Origin: http://192.168.29.129:8090
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Comment: What does the request you are sending look like?

Comment: @afelisatti See above for request headers

Comment: Did you modify the boundary parameter on purpose? Cause that doesn't seem right...

Comment: @afelisatti I have modified them. I copied this from the debug tool in firefox. I belive its just compacted for viewing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting parseRequest="false" on the http listener

```
<http:listener config-ref="HttpListenerConfig" path="/*" parseRequest="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know what the problem is without logs. However, why to use jersey for this? You can upload the files in multipart request simply using the http connector. Check this page for information on how to build multipart requests: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-request-connector

If you still have compelling reasons for staying with Jersey, make sure that the jersey multipart support is enabled for Jersey (take in count that Jersey was upgraded in Mule 3.6)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.